# Program produces wrong Output

Tags: java

Having trouble with the program below. I am basically novice in Java right now.

The code looks like below:

```
public class IfElseIf{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        int date=26;
        int month=9;
        int year=1995;
        if ((date>=1 | date <=10) || (month>=1 | month <=4) || year==1995)
        {
            System.out.println("Your bday is in between 1-10/1-4/1995");        

        }
        else if((date>=11 | date <=20) || (month >=5 | month <=8) || year==1995)
        {
            System.out.println("Your bday is in between 11-20/5-8/1995");
        } 
        else if((date>=21 | date<=31) || (month >=9 | month <=12) || year==1995)
        {
            System.out.println("Your bday is in between 21-31/9-12/1995");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Your bday not found");
        }
     }
}
```

On running the above, it gives me the following output:

```
Your bday is in between 1-10/1-4/1995
```

What might be possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong operators; `|` is bitwise "OR", and you want logical "AND", which is `&&`.

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your help. I too spotted the same .

Comment: OP also needs to replace his short-circuit "OR" with "AND".